# Adding multiple annotations on WKInterfaceMap

Tags: ios, annotations, watchkit

I am trying to add multiple annotations to my map but the watch is only showing one. This is what I am doing.

```
for (RestaurantObject *restaurant in nearbyMapArray) {
     CLLocationCoordinate2D mapLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([restaurant.latitude doubleValue], [restaurant.longitude doubleValue]);
    [self.map addAnnotation:mapLocation withPinColor: WKInterfaceMapPinColorRed];
    MKCoordinateSpan coordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1); 
    [self.map setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapLocation, coordinateSpan))];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are setting the region at each annotation location. Try setting it once.

```
regionCoordinate = ?
MKCoordinateSpan coordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1); 
[self.map setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegionMake(regionCoordinate, coordinateSpan))];

for (RestaurantObject *restaurant in nearbyMapArray) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D mapLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([restaurant.latitude doubleValue], [restaurant.longitude doubleValue]);
    [self.map addAnnotation:mapLocation withPinColor: WKInterfaceMapPinColorRed];
}
```

You may need to play around with the coordinateSpan value and the region coordinate to show them all. I am wondering if there is a maximum of 5 annotations allowed though.